# How can I set the client access type to confidential in Keycloak 20.0.3?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

Where can I set the client access type (as confidential) in the keyclock 20.0.3 ?
I am not able to find a option to set the access type.

When creating a client, there is no option also after creation, in the settings menu there's no access type option.

I have attached a screenshot for the same.

[image: No option to set access type]

Answer (score 5):

In the same page as in your screenshot you should have an option to toggle `Client authentication`, once it's on the client should be confidential. The tooltip for it is:

> This defines the type of the OIDC client. When it's ON, the OIDC type is set to confidential access type. When it's OFF, it is set to public access type